cached_video_player:verifyReleaseResources'. executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action >
I'm encountering an error while generating a release build for my Flutter project. The project uses the cached_video_player and appinio_video_player plugins. The build works smoothly in debug mode, but I'm facing issues in release mode.
Execution failed for task ':cached_video_player:verifyReleaseResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:C:\Users\HP.gradle\caches\transforms-3\87f0e673dc4ee6b514e9d5964fa729a9\transformed\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

Here's my build.gradle file:
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.23"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName "7.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    
}


can you post your app gradle file?

use this instead of cached video Player
this package include changes required for cached video Player
https://pub.dev/packages/video_cached_player
